# TFS Build Template Nested Arguments

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

Is it possible to nest TFS build template arguments in one another?

Example (Set via build definition ui):

```
$(ToolsRoot) = E:\BuildTools

$(MSPECTools) = $(ToolsRoot)\MSpec\
```

Alternatively, is it possible to use environmental variables.

I have tried both, and neither seemed to work.

I need to find a way of setting the build root dynamically, as it differs on our various build servers.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have implemented a topology like the this:[image]

So, you need to control the root for each Agent.
If you open the TFS Admin Console > Build configuration in Build Machine #1 you 'll see the Build Controller & Agents A.1 & A.2.
If you open TFS Admin Console > Build configuration in Build Machine #2 you 'll see Agents A.3, A.4, A.5 & A.6.
For any given build Agent, if you click on "Properties" you 'll see the "Working Directory" entry, which typically is set to something like `$(SystemDrive)\Builds\$(BuildAgentId)\`. On runtime this is transformed into something like `C:\Builds\55`.
For any given build, in the build definition area "Workspaces" this "Working Directory" equals the entry `$(SourceDir)`.

Suppose you have set in Agent A.1 a working directory "C:\A.1\Build" & in Agent A.2 "C:\A.2\Build". 
In order to get what you need, you have to set in the build definition a mapping to `$(SourceDir)\Template`

Comment: See also section "More about the Working Directory Property" of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399135.aspx

Comment: Hi, thanks for a great answer. The topology is correct. Unfortunately my example was a bit misleading, my bad. The folders I need to set are not the working directory, but actually folders containing our build tools and unit test runners.